# removing duplicate records in list

Tags: java, list, struts2

Hi while developing one of my web application i am storing the user information in to an ArrayList based on sql query executed, it contain duplicate objects how to remove duplicate objects in list , i already tried some method but it still not working. 
**This Is My Code Correct me where i am wrong**

```
      public ArrayList loadData() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
    ArrayList userList = new ArrayList();
    String url = "";
    String dbName = "";
    String userName = "";
    String password = "";
    Connection con = null;
    Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver");
    con = DriverManager.getConnection(url + dbName, userName, password);
    PreparedStatement ps = null;
    try {
        String name;
        String fatherName;
        int Id;
        String filePath;
        int age;
        String address;
        String query = "SELECT NAME,FATHERNAME,AGE,ADDRESS,ID,FILEPATH FROM USER_INFORMATION ,USER_PHOTO WHERE ID=USER_ID";
        ps = con.prepareStatement(query);
        ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
        while (rs.next()) {
            name = rs.getString(1);
            fatherName = rs.getString(2);
            age = rs.getInt(3);
            address = rs.getString(4);
            Id = rs.getInt(5);
            filePath=rs.getString(6);
           /* if(flag)
            {
                prev=Id;
                flag=false;
            }
            else if(Id==prev)
            {
                TEMP=TEMP+";"+filePath;
            }*/
            //PhotoList = PhotoList(Id, con);
            UserData list = new UserData();
            list.setName(name);
            list.setFatherName(fatherName);
            list.setAge(age);
            list.setAddress(address);
            list.setId(Id);
   //       list.setFilePath(filePath);
            userList.add(list);
        }
        ps.close();
        con.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    ArrayList al = new ArrayList();
    HashSet hs = new HashSet();
    hs.addAll(userList);
    al.clear();
    al.addAll(hs);
    return al;
}
```

And My Bean Class contant is

```
    public class UserData {

private String name;
private String fatherName;
private int Id;
//private String filePath;
private int age;
private String address;
public UserData()
{

}

public UserData(String name, String fatherName,int Id, int age,String address)
{
    this.name = name;
    this.fatherName = fatherName;
    this.Id = Id;
    //this.filePath=filePath;
    this.age=age;
    this.address=address;
}
//GETTER AND SETTER..
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a Collection of objects that does not have a specific order and you don't want duplicates, it's better for you just to use a Set like for example HashSet, or, if in your set the order is important, the TreeSet.

Just remember to override the hash and equals methods.

if you add this to your bean everything should work:

```
public int hashCode() {
    return (name + fatherName+ Id + filePath + age + address).hashCode();
}

public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    return ( hashCode() == obj.hashCode() );
}
```

Comment: The asker is adding the list to a set in an attempt to dedupe but this isn't working.

Comment: Thanks Jim .                                                         Ok after including it to bean how to call it will it implicitly called or do we need to call explicitly.@jim

Comment: When you call the hs.add( x ) the equals is called implicitly and the item is added only if there is not an element y such that x.equals(y) is true.

Answer (score 2):

General Idea: Use [Set](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Set.html), not [List](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/List.html). But you must override hash and equals of the class.

Comment: This is the suggested way - as the code is a lot more readable and also using the standard interfaces helps get the idea of your class across to others who read your code.

Answer (score 0):

All duplicates must be removed at an SQL level. Your SQL is suggesting that it could be generating duplicate records.

```
String query = "SELECT NAME,FATHERNAME,AGE,ADDRESS,ID,FILEPATH FROM USER_INFORMATION ,USER_PHOTO WHERE ID=USER_ID";
```

What does the clause `ID = USER_ID` mean? Shouldn't you be passing in that value as an input to your query?

Also, is the column `ID` a primary key? Otherwise, use a where clause that doesn't generate duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

Your userdata class does not implement equals or hashcode. This means two instances created with the same values will not be counted as duplicates. This is why the set contains duplicates.

For example

```
UserData u1 = new UserData("Foo", "bar",1, 1,"baz");

UserData u2 = new UserData("Foo", "bar",1, 1,"baz");
```

u1 and u2 are not considered equal as they are different objects. Adding an equals and hashcode method should fix this. However even better is adarshr's idea of removing dupes in the SQL.

Comment: Guys The Main Thing is i have to get the full information of the users and display their information like name age address.. etc along with their uploaded photos name using display tag in struts, as u already know that each user having more than two to three photos. while selecting the records from db obviously we will get same user information with different photos name and display tag will display all that repeated information. so can any one suggest a way to overcome this, so that it display one one user record with all his uploaded photos name.